# Why isn't my jquery menu working?

Tags: jquery-ui

I've checked the code over meticulously but I cant find anything wrong with it.
I modeled it after the menu [here](https://jqueryui.com/menu/) but that's not really working out for me. Basically, all that comes up is ur run of the mill ul.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script type ="text/javascript">
     
      <!-- Dropdown menu -->
        <script>
      $( function() {
      $( "#dropMenu" ).menu();
      } );
     </script>
    <style>
    
     .ui-menu { width: 150px; }
     body{
     
      background-image: url("background.jpg");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
     
     }
     h1{
     
      font-family:"Lucida Calligraphy","Lucida Fax", Arial;
      color: Beige;
      text-align:center;
     
     }
     #footer{
     
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      background-color: rgba(20,90,50,.8);
      margin-bottom: 0px;
      padding-bottom: 0px;
      border-radius:10%;
      text-align:center;
      color:beige;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
     
     
     }
     #square{
     
      height:200px;
      width: 350px;
      background-color:rgba(20, 90,50);
     
     }
     #wrapper{
     
      background-color: rgba(20, 90,50, .5);
      margin: auto;
      border-radius:6%;
     
     }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
     <div id="wrapper"> 
    
      <h1>Serenity Landscaping <br /> and Property Management</h1>
      <!-- <div id="square"></div>  -->
       <ul id="menu">
        <li><div>Menu</div>
        <ul>
         <li><div>Home</div></li>
         <li><div>Side Biz</div></li>
         <li><div>Portfolio</div></li>
         <li><div>Contact Us</div></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
       </ul>
     
      
      <div id="footer"><p>SLPM is owner operated and is dedicated to providing the highest quality service to all customers.
      <br/>Services in the landscape and property maintenance field</p></div>
     
     </div>
     
     <script type ="text/javascript">
     
      var windowWidth=$(window).width();
      var wrapperWidth=(windowWidth/2);
      var windowHeight=$(window).height();
      var wrapperHeight=windowHeight;
      $("#wrapper").height(wrapperHeight+"px");
      $("#wrapper").width(wrapperWidth+"px");
      
      <!-- footer width resizing -->
      var footerWidth;
      footerWidth = $("#footer").css("width", wrapperWidth);
      <!-- footer width resizing -->
      
      <!--alert(wrapperWidth);-->
      <!--alert(windowWidth);-->
     </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: what exactly not working?which error it is giving?

Answer (score 0):

The first issue I have seen is you are using wrong `id` for initializing your menu.

I have created a fiddle for your code and did some minor change and it is working fine.

There were only silly mistakes.

Here is working fiddle.

[Working Fiffle](https://jsfiddle.net/jk07jk6e/)

Comment: what other minor changes because i fixed the ID and it's STILL not working lol

Comment: is it giving any error?Compare your code with my fiddle code.